# Codeigniter 3 session driver. Is it better to use databse or file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

Can someone explain to me the sessions driver on codeigniter 3 and what is my best option to use, I currently use database but I don't know how much data I can store in it, I use the session for storing several user data and a small shopping cart.

I read the doc's but it's just not explained in apples and oranges :S

Thank for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of the database driver will always be far better than file based session backend.

It has no practical limit that is typically of concern, but do note that the session is stored as a single row, limiting your session data approximately to the database's row size limit. This is usually 65,536 bytes, which is more than sufficient for a typical shopping cart.*

```
Storage Requirements
BLOB, TEXT as L + 2 bytes, where L < 216
```

Above is from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: When using database sessions, the performance will show that on few sessions, it may be faster, but when the system is under load, the file system will most of the time be performing better. File-based sessions have scaling issues, but for single server setups, where the system is quite busy, file-based sessions will most likely out-perform database sessions.